# how to convert datetime format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-ajax

hi i am giving a textbox to user and ajax calender extender to select date in dd/mm/yyyy format after that i am using following function to convert it to mm/dd/yyyy format for inserting in to sql server database  but it not work well in one page i got error datetime conversion  error and in other i have to enter yyyy/mm/dd format to insert data into database. my code works fine in localhost but in server these errors are coming . my function is

```
 protected string getDate_MDY(string inDate)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
    DateTime dtProjectStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(inDate);
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    return (Convert.ToDateTime(dtProjectStartDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
}
```

and for inserting i used it like getDate_MDY(txtcreatedate.text);

i just want to insert my correct date in to database by taking dd/mm/yyyy format from text box. . please show me right way to modify it...thanks

Comment: All date values going into the database should be yyyy-MM-dd format

Comment: Actually @Hugo that format is not safe; try `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH; SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME,'2015-03-11'));` - you would expect `mars` but you get `novembre`. And French language is not the only setting that can cause this problem. See https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Comment: Why are you trying to convert a regional and ambiguously formatted string to a different regional and ambiguously formatted string? To hand a date to SQL Server you want a strongly-typed DATE or DATETIME parameter, and you want to stop worrying about formats. If you absolutely need to pass a string literal, the *only* safe format for date without time is `YYYYMMDD`. Anything else can be misinterpreted. I also suggest not showing users `dd/mm/yyyy` because they can misinterpret those just like software can.

Comment: Interesting, thanks @AaronBertrand, Dates are such a pain.

Comment: i have to show dd/mm/yyyy format because users use this format commonly. they want to see day of date first

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact` instead of changing the current thread culture. Both of these methods have overloads that take a culture to use when parsing the string.

For example:

```
protected string getDate_MDY(string inDate)
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(inDate, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
    return date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
}
```

This isn't the most efficient way to do this (you'd probably want to cache the **CultureInfo** instances for starters) but it will do what you asked for (ie. convert a date/time string from one culture to another).

However, as someone pointed out in the comments, you shouldn't be passing date *strings* to a SQL command. Instead, they should be defined as date/time parameters in the SQL command:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("<your connection string>"))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO (sometable) VALUES (@somedatecolumn)";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    var parameter = new SqlParameter("@somedatecolumn", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime);
    parameter.Value = <your date/time value>; // a DateTime value, not a string
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: i used these 2 also but same error.  i am taking smalldatetime for colmn and in procedure is there any problem with this

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should only add DateTimeFormatInfo to your Convert.ToDateTime(inDate) --> Convert.ToDateTime(inDate, DateTimeFormatInfo)

```
        System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = null;
        DateTime dtProjectStartDate = new DateTime(2008, 4, 10); //year, month, day

        ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"); 
        dtfi = ci.DateTimeFormat;

        txtBox.Text = dtProjectStartDate.ToString("d", dtfi); // 10/4/2008


        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ciForSQL = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
        System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dtfiForSQL = ciForSQL.DateTimeFormat;
        DateTime dtForSQL = Convert.ToDateTime(txtBox.Text, dtfiForSQL);
        txtBoxForSQL.Text = dtForSQL.ToString("d", dtfiForSQL); // 10/4/2008
```

Comment: In shorter way:  txtBox.Text = new DateTime(2012, 3, 14).ToString("d", new CultureInfo("en-GB")); //14/03/2012
            txtBoxForSQL.Text = new DateTime(2012, 3, 14).ToString("d", new CultureInfo("en-US"));//3/14/2012

Answer (score -1):

Use..[DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

```
DateTime.ParseExact("12/02/21 10:56:09", "yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    ).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: Passing this m/d/y string to SQL Server is just as dangerous as passing the original d/m/y string.

Comment: he's not asking in Sql server, see  example. @AaronBertrand

Comment: it's a c# method returning a date time as string in a specific format.

Comment: My point is that you don't want a string, and neither does the OP - he/she just hasn't realized it yet.

Comment: @user3373573 What does "not working" mean? (Also, let me guess, you wrote this code a few days ago, and this is the first time you've tested it when the day was > 12?)

Comment: i just want to insert my correct  date in to database by taking dd/mm/yyyy format from text box. there is around 300 active users for my software they are using it daily . but from 4-5 day there is date format issue in my software.. please show me right way to modify it...thanks